# How to partition a sample into representative subsamples?

Tags: sampling, survey-sampling, subsampling, representative

The problem is the following: take a sample $X$ of the general population $\Omega$. Each element of $\Omega$ (and hence, each element of $X$) is described by a vector of characteristics, each characteristics has a finite support (think of gender, age, education level...). The joint distribution of these characteristics in $\Omega$ is known. Take a measure of dissimilarity between distributions (say, the Kullback-Leibler divergence), $d$. We want to find a partition of $X$ in $n>1$ subsamples $(S_1,\ldots,S_n)$ such that the subsamples are the most representative possible of the general population. In practice, we would take a criterion like minimizing the average dissimilarity between $S_i$ ($i:1...n$) and $\Omega$.
I am interested in any variant of the problem: e.g. where one does not choose $n$ ex ante, or where the $(S_i)_{i:1...n}$ are still mutually exclusive but do not cover all $X$, or with another choice of criterion. I am mostly interested in algorithmic implementation of a solution. A bibliographic research didn't give me any interesting result, but maybe I tried the wrong keywords.

Comment: Assuming $|S_i|=|X|/n$ for all $i\leq n$, the $S_i$ cannot be more representative of $\Omega$ than $X$, on average. So the original problem amounts to finding a partition of $X$ in miniature versions representative of $X$ ($\Omega$ plays a role only in the variants).

Comment: This seems close to the problem of [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(statistics)) in statistics. For example: an experiment designed to test the effects of a new pesticide will include in both the treatment and control groups high elevation and low elevation areas, to block the elevation factor which may otherwise confound the results. 
On this, Deaton & Cartwright (2018) report: "Morgan and Rubin (2012) suggest the Mahalanobis D–statistic be used as a criterion and use Fisher's randomization inference to calculate standard errors that take the re-randomization into account."

Comment: Zhou et al. (2021) "Why polls fail to predict elections" confirm that the simple quota method (currently used) doesn't work well as it fails on joint distribution.

Answer (score 0):

[Deville & Tillé (2004)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/sjos.12016) and [Grafström & Schelin (2014)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/sjos.12016) define representativity and provide algorithms that can select a representative sample of a given size $n$ from a population of size $K$.

As a first approximation to solve the problem, their method can be adapted to select $n$ representative subsamples of size $k$ by repeatedly applying one of their algorithm on the population of $X$ that is not yet included in a subsample. Granted, the first subsample produced will be more representative than the last one, but this is a good first step in the variant where the subsamples do not cover all $X$.

Note that their algorithms can accommodate the cases where $X$ is not representative of $\Omega$, as they rely on *inclusion weights*, that should be set according to true $\Omega$ frequencies if one is ready that the subsamples do not cover all $X$, and uniformly (to $1/n$) if one wants to partition $X$ in $n$ miniature versions of $X$.